# How to get title from WKInterfaceButton

Tags: swift, watchkit

To get title there is function:

```
setTitle
```

But how to get title of WKInterfaceButton as string ?

I did not found anything in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/index.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't get the state of any WKInterface UI element like buttons (WKInterfaceButton) label (WKInterfaceLabel) etc. I think this is designed by Apple like this because it involve under the hood communication between the extension running on your iOS device & the watch App. To save this overhead there are no getters and the extension should keep track of the state change (it is the one that can change the state).

Comment: You can also subclass `WKInterfaceButton` and add a `setTitle` and backing instance variable.

Comment: @progrmr From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/index.html): Do not subclass or create instances of this class yourself

Comment: @progrmr In Xcode 6.2 it isn't even possible to subclass any WKInterface*-class thats not WKInterfaceController...

Comment: @Jack you're right, they say do not subclass.  So if you can't subclass it, then your next best option is to keep track of the title in a separate property.