# retrieve the text of WKInterfaceLabel in swift

Tags: ios, swift, label, watchkit

How can i get the text of label in Swift or Objective-C in WatchKit?
The class is not UILabel but it is WKInterfaceLabel.
I have also tried to search in [class library of apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014960-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4) but there is only three methods are available.

Comment: Another victim can not read text from WKInterfaceButton :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205623/how-to-get-title-from-wkinterfacebutton

Comment: yes, there is also no gesture recognizer available.
This is very bad.

Comment: if you find any other way to get text from WKInterfaceLabl please post it as a answer.

Answer (score 6):

**By reading [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014960-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4)** it is not possible you have to maintain track which you set in label
looks like apple is very strict about this class you can not create a subclass or direct instance of this.
[image]

They only talk about how to set the text not about getting text
[image]

Non of it's supper class have method to get text
[image]

If its posible You can create extension of WKInterfaceLabel and get text 
but no idea if apple approve it or not.

**My Conclusion is**
Its not possible directly by any way to get text
you can do some trick but make sure that its acceptable by apple.

---

Friendly speaking i am not much aware about watch SDK, but if you dealing with any beta version of type thing let hope that apple will add that thing in new version as they had wrote
[image]

---

Reference of all i wrote and images are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014960-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4)

Answer (score 4):

Just have a `@property (nonatomic) NSString *currentText;` That everytime you update or set your `WKInterfaceLabel` you also set or update.

It's not the best solution, but it works for now, while Apple doesn't have any official way to get it.

Comment: Currently I'm doing same. But let me know if there is alternative is there

Comment: I've been looking for a ilbrary or something, but with the Watch being so new there isn't a whole lot

Answer (score 1):

Apple has declared `WKInterfaceLabel` class with only *setter property* and *no getter property*.

This screenshot shows class declaration of `WKInterfaceLabel` present in WatchKit framework.

[image: Screenshot]