# How to send Text from ViewController (iOS) to InterfaceController (Watch Kit)?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am creating an iOS app to display the decibels from the microphone to a UILabel. I completely forgot to think ahead for a WatchKit target device and don't have too much experience with it. I was wondering is there a way to send the .text info from the UILabel in my iOS ViewController to the WatchKit InterfaceController? I tried sending it with my own class but its not displaying anything. I did notice the labels are different. The WatchKit uses WKInterfaceLabel instead of UILabel.

What I've done so far:
1. Created a new class to allow a string argument to update its own label with a public function.
2. Changed the main class of the watch to the one I just created. 
3. Created a variable to reference the new class created. 
4. Send label.text as an argument to the class to update watch label.text
5. Public function works but not with my current updateMeters() function with 0.5 ms timer

- I just want to sync up my label from viewController to the label on the watchKit - interfaceController
- I've tried WCSession but don't know exactly what to put for the WCConnectivity Delegate requirements
- I've even tried writing to a text file from ios and reading the file from watch but it seems their file paths are different too.

EDITED:

Finally got it to work using WatchConnectivity Kit and by using DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {})

Comment: Have you tried that : [link_stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456160/retrieve-the-text-of-wkinterfacelabel-in-swift)

Comment: I read that already but it just explained that the WatchKit label is read only then someone else recommended to use the @property but I can't even get that to show up. I just want the label from my viewController to be in sync with the label from the WatchKit interfaceController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using:

- WatchConnectivity Kit
- DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {})

Data sent with applicationContext

Answer (score 1):

The primary way is by using the [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) framework.

Comment: I tried using the WatchConnectivity framework but don't really understand what to put under the required protocols when adding in the delegate. "func sessionDidBecomeInactive", func sessionDidDeactivate, func session...activationDidCompleteWith"