# Find height and width of a WKInterfaceImage

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

I want to programmatically render a `UIImage` and then display it on Apple Watch in a `WKInterfaceImage`, which height and width I set to "Relative to Container" (so that it basically takes up the entire screen space).
How can I obtain the `WKInterfaceImage`'s width and and height? As far as I can see, there is no `frame`-, `border`- oder `layer`-property I can access from my extension's code. So what is the proper way to get this information?

Weird enough I have found out that there is a setWidth and setHeight method, but I can't find according getter methods.

At the end of the day I am basically looking for the Watch Kit equivalent to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
//...
var width = imageView.frame.width
var height = imageView.frame.height
```

Comment: Similar question answered here (for WKInterfaceButton, but the concept is same) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205623/how-to-get-title-from-wkinterfacebutton/27211175#27211175

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very common misconception with WatchKit.

You cannot query runtime data in this type of way. The reason is that Apple doesn't want you pinging the Watch every time you need to read a value. They want to optimize battery life as much as possible. Instead, you need to "know" what the width and height of the `WKInterfaceImage`. You defined it in the Storyboard, so you know exactly what it already is. [Xscope](http://xscopeapp.com) can be really helpful in figuring out exactly what the size is. Once you know the size, you need to store that size in your `WKInterfaceController` so that you have the data at runtime.

```
class ImageInterfaceController : WKInterfaceController {
    let imageSize38mm = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    let imageSize42mm = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
}
```

Hope that helps shed some light on the fact that you can't query layout and sizing information at runtime the same way you can in an iOS app.

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: How about 44mm watch?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you just can't set the width and hight of a an image programmatically. Set the image mode to size to fit content and also the same to the container view. It will resize itself to fit the content.

Quoting the only available attributes from the class reference
[image]

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure if I got ur point (or u got mine): I'm not trying to SET the ImageViews width and height, but rather GET them.

Comment: Ah, sorry! My bad. Is the photo itself is the only element in view?

Comment: Yes, it is... Taking that into account your answer let me to another approach anyway: Construct a square UIImage and then aspect fit it into the WKInterfaceImage!

Comment: Using relative to container confuses the issue even more...

Is there a way to know which size watch is connected to the iPhone app?

Comment: You can rely on the contentFrame property in your WKInterfaceController.